# Extracting type and offset from struct field in template

Tags: d

Notice: even that my example are from OpenGL, this is not an OpenGL question, but general D question.

**Background:** In my gaming project, I have shader class to help interfacing to GLSL code. Setting uniforms work nicely:

```
uniform(string name, float value) --> glUniform1f(...)
uniform(string name, mat4 m) --> glUniformMatrix4fv( ...)
etc. etc.
```

That is, it chooses right function depending on the type of the parameter, and so when I modify my code, it automatically changes to use correct function (assuming that I don't have type conflicts between D and GLSL).

My troubles are implementing somewhat similar mechanism to bind attributes. I have VERTEX structure:

```
struct VERTEX { ...; vec3 pos; ... }
```

For binding attribute, in addition to know the type of the field, I need the offset, but I don't need the values. I managed to write clumpsy implementation, where call looks like:

```
vbo.attrib!(typeof(mesh.VERTEX.pos))("vert_pos", mesh.VERTEX.pos.offsetof);
```

And VBO.attrib is implemented like this:

```
void attrib(T: vec2)(string name, ulong offset) { /* 2 floats from offset */ }
void attrib(T: vec3)(string name, ulong offset) { /* 3 floats from offset */ }
```

**Question:** Is there a way to make this simpler and more elegant? Generally, I don't like duplicating the field when calling, that is, first extract the type to choose correct attrib binding function, and then separately send offset. I would like the function call look something like this:

```
vbo.attrib("vert_pos", mesh.VERTEX.pos);
```

...And the template to extract both type and offset from the argument. I have read D template guides and tutorials, but I have't yet figured out how to implement templates like that. Is it possible and how?

**Clarification:** I have a feeling that I'm already close, I just don't have enough imagination (and knowledge from D templates and mixins) to implement the first phase:

```
XXX(name, field)
--> some unknown magic
--> vbo.attrib!(typeof(field))(name,field.offsetof)
--> void attrib(T: vec2)(string name, ulong offset) { /* arguments for GL call */ }
```

---

**EDIT:** With mixins, I managed to make it look like this:

```
    template attrib(string name, string field)
    {
        const char[] attrib =
            "vbo.attrib!" ~
            "(typeof(" ~ field ~ "))" ~
            "(\"" ~ name ~ "\", " ~ field ~ ".offsetof);";
    }

    mixin(attrib!("vert_pos", "mesh.VERTEX.pos"));
    mixin(attrib!("vert_uv", "mesh.VERTEX.uv"));
```

To be honest, it (calling) looks even more complex to use than my current one, so I keep my current and look for nicer-looking solution.

Comment: You might be able to just pass the name as a template argument, then use mixin or __traits(getMember) to get the offset and type from it and forward that to your attrib function call.

Comment: Or an alias argument: `void attrib(alias field)(string name) { alias T = typeof(field); auto offset = field.offsetof; /* rest of your code */ } ` But I'm not sure that the offsetof will actually work on an alias like that.

Comment: blargh the alias option lets you get the data, but not actually call the function, complains about needing `this`. :(

Comment: Yeah, I was just about write comment that alias assumes that you are sending something in (I get: "Error: template instance attrib!(pos) cannot use local 'pos' as parameter to non-global template attrib(alias field)(string name)" - I try that init, just a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are really very close to the solution. this works with DMD git head:

```
import std.stdio;

struct vec2 {
  float a, b;
}

struct vec3 {
  float a, b, c;
}

struct VERTEX {
  vec3 pos;
  vec2 uv;
}

void attrib(T: vec2) (string name, ulong offset) {
  writefln("vec2: name=%s; ofs=%s", name, offset);
}

void attrib(T: vec3) (string name, ulong offset) {
  writefln("vec3: name=%s; ofs=%s", name, offset);
}


static void attrib(string name, alias field) () {
  attrib!(typeof(field))(name, field.offsetof);
}


void main () {
  attrib!("vert_pos", VERTEX.pos); // outputs "vec3: name=vert_pos; ofs=0"
  attrib!("vert_uv", VERTEX.uv); // outputs: "vec2: name=vert_uv; ofs=12"
}
```

unfortunately i don't have official 2.066 release to check if it works with it. this will **not** work with 2.065 for sure, so you are out of luck with GDC (as it still using 2.065).

the trick is in `static`, which means "this template doesn't need any context".

p.s. just checked it, and yes, this works with 2.066 release.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it is possible :D